# Unable to prevent automatic hyphenation

Tags: android, xamarin.android, hyphenation

I'm adding a custom TextView programmatically but I cannot figure out how to prevent automatic hyphenation of some words that begin with a "-" or "/".

I'm adding the TextView at some point here:

```
var myTextView = new TextView(Activity);
myTextView.Text = "This is a test -XX -XX -XX -XX";

// Apply style
myTextView = ApplyCustomStyle(myTextView);

Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    myLinearLayout.AddView(myTextView);
});
```

And then I'm trying to set "HyphenationFrequency" to "None":

```
private TextView ApplyCustomStyle(TextView mTextView)
{
    mTextView.SetTextColor(new ApplyTheme().GetColor(DesiredColor.MainText));
    mTextView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 14);

    var myTextViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    myTextViewParams.SetMargins(25, 5, 0, 0);
    mTextView.LayoutParameters = myTextViewParams;

    mTextView.HyphenationFrequency = HyphenationFrequency.None;

    return mTextView;
}
```

But it isn't working as expected (actually nothing changes). I guess Android detects the "-" as an automatic hyphen character and I'm getting this result:

```
This is a test -XX -XX -
XX -XX
```

While the result I'm looking for is:

```
This is a test -XX -XX 
-XX -XX
```

As the string length is just an example and it can change considerably from time to time, I've discarded changing the TextView width or any other similar solution (at least for the time being).

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: What is your min version. [HyphenationFrequency only work above 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHyphenationFrequency(int))

Comment: Thanks Joe. I was using 16, but after updating to 23 or higher it's still not working. Not sure why, though.

Comment: I suggest you create a custom `TextView`, in it's `OnMeasure` method, you need to measure and judge whether move "-" and words which behinds "-" to next line. Maybe it is a huge project to make it.

Comment: Thank you once again. I did solve the issue by replacing all the "-" for non-breaking hyphens (&#8209;). It works for me, but I'm still wondering why the HyphenationFrequency did not work as I was expecting (even after changing the minVersion). I could not find much documentations or examples either.